# How is filler conveyed in a gloss?

Tags: spoken-language, interlinear-gloss, filler

[Fillers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_%28linguistics%29) are used in many languages when the speaker signals that he or she is thinking but has not yet finished talking. Things in English like *umm*, *er*, *uh* etc.

Is there something that can be put in the interlinear gloss to convey this? Something like FILL, or a similar abbreviation?

Comment: What do spoken corpora do?

Comment: Most of the stuff I read that uses morphological glosses isn't interested in these channel-level details of conversations, so fillers aren't even transcribed.  The kind of work that's usually interested in fillers, pauses, hesitations, corrections etc. is conversation analysis; and then there are [entire systems of notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_(linguistics)#Transcription_systems) for how to transcribe conversations.

Answer (score 3):

In a project that produced a corpus of (spoken) Nigerian English we used HES for *hesitation*. I've also come across HES in articles in linguistics journals, but not FILL.